# Symfony2 - "\" when saving ext field

Tags: symfony

I have a problem when I'm saving a text field into a text field.

For example, when I'm tapping

```
I don't know
```

when I read the database I have

```
I don\'t know
```

Any helps please
Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the similar issue. I overcame this situation by off the magic quotes.
This is due to magic quotes of symfony2. So you need to off it. Inorder to off magic quotes

go to the yourprojectfolder/web/.htaccess inside it add the below line

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

below is the example of an htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off     //this line off magic quotes.
</IfModule>
```

happy coding...

Comment: I totally turn off "magic_quotes_..." in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini but it still escape quotes. Your solution works but I don't know the problem my system has.